# Why no bluetooth UUID are delivered on Android 4.3?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

I have some code that listens to bluetooth discovery events, listing out the discovered devices and their UUIDs.

Now, this code was working perfectly on Androids 2.3 through 4.1. However, on 4.3 (didn't try 4.2), all of a sudden, I don't see UUIDs anywhere anymore. The only difference seems to be just sheer lack of any UUID information.

Here is the broadcast receiver code:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "BTReceiver got action " + action);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

            BluetoothDevice device =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            Parcelable[] extraUIIDs = device.getUuids();

            if (extraUIIDs == null) {
                device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
            }
        }

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {

            BluetoothDevice device =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            Parcelable[] pUUIDs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);

            if (pUUIDs == null) {
                pUUIDs = device.getUuids();
                Log.d(TAG, "No UUIDs in intent, trying from device : "+pUUIDs);
            }

        }

    }
```

In older Androids, I would ether see UUIDs in the device object, or received along with UUID action. In 4.3, I still receive the UUID action, but the UUID array is `null` in both the intent and the device object.

Again, the *only* difference is the Android version (and device), but it worked consistently on all androids I could get my hands on, as long as they were lower than 4.2.